# How to convert a running SQL Server code into a stored procedure with the proper parameters to pass to the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, point

If I run this in a query from SQL Server that works:

```
DECLARE @Point geography;
DECLARE @Polygon geography;

-- Set the values for the point and polygon
SET @Point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-71.56 44.50)', 4326);
SET @Polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-72.69449829101593 45.668674540806705,-72.10535644531258 45.77413811271179,-71.64118408203115 45.59665341601985,-72.96692970976399 45.28088342792443,-72.69449829101593 45.668674540806705))', 4326);

-- Determine if the point is within the polygon
IF @Polygon.STContains(@Point) = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'The point is within the polygon';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'The point is not within the polygon';
END
```

Now if I am trying to create a stored procedure, but it's always saying the data conversion is not correct

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [NSGIS].CheckPointInPolygon
    @PlanePoint NVARCHAR(255),
    @PolygonInfos NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Point GEOGRAPHY;
    DECLARE @Polygon GEOGRAPHY;
    
    -- Set the values for the point and polygon
    SET @Point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(@PlanePoint)', 4326);
    SET @Polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((@PolygonInfos))', 4326);

    -- Determine if the point is within the polygon
    IF @Polygon.STContains(@Point) = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The point is within the polygon';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The point is not within the polygon';
    END
END
```

Now to access the stored procedure, I use this code:

```
DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC    @return_value = [NSGIS].[CheckPointInPolygon]
        @PlanePoint = 'POINT(-71.99 45.33)',
        @PolygonInfos = '-122.34900 47.65100, -122.23700 47.65100, -122.23700 47.73900'

SELECT  @return_value AS "Return Value"
```

What is wrong? Sorry I am not able to figure it out.

Many thanks for your help

Mike

Comment: You can't reference scalar variables inside string literals like that. Have you tried concatenating them like `geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + @PlanePoint + ')', 4326)` noting, of course, while keeping `POINT(` and `)` in here that the `@PlanePoint` parameter shouldn't also contain `POINT(` and `)` in it; or perhaps more simply just `geography::STPointFromText(@PlanePoint, 4326)`?

Comment: Aside... `POLYGON` definitions require a minimum of four coordinates and, also, the first and last coordinates should be the same so as to form a closed loop. i.e.: the minimum polygon is a triangle.

Comment: Aside... by convention the return status of a stored procedure is meant to indicate error state, i.e.: 0 == success, any other value an error number (application-specific). If you wish to return data from a stored procedure it should be either in the form of result set(s), or it should be `OUTPUT` parameters. To improve the usefulness of procedures with this kind of functionality they might better be written as User-Defined Functions which then allows you to reference them within `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements without the need for an `EXEC` (and potentially cursors).

Comment: Oh many thanks for answers, I will give a try but when I tried it is giving these errors

Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NSGIS.CheckPointInPolygon, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 2]
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 17 of the input. The input has @PlanePoint.
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeDouble()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)
 ...